# How to solve error, adding a new data store with postgis

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, postgis, geoserver

I'm trying to add a new data store with postgis on geoserver, but there's an error.

[image]

I'm using Tomcat 9 with geoserver 2.19.1
and PostgreSQL 12

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please post the error message as text, not an image. This has [many advantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), e.g. it would be easy to decode the UTF-8 (Hangul?) text wrongly interpreted as ISO 8859-1. BTW: check the database credentials you provided, one of them is `null`.

Comment: What is the 'database credentials'? How can i check it?

Comment: Look into the [datastore](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/stores.html) you configured. One field between host, dbname, user or password is empty.

Comment: Finally solved problem. I sincerely thank you all.

Comment: Please, post the solution as answer.

Comment: How can i post your comment as an answer? or you mean i should post an answer myself?

Comment: You should post an answer yourself explaining what didn't work. It might help somebody else with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comments by Piotr,

> [...] Check the database credentials you provided, one of them is null.
>
> Look into the [datastore](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/stores.html) you configured. One field between host, dbname, user or password is empty.

This helped me solve my problem

The problem was I didn't fill the dbname.